# How can I use the decode list to encode for codeMessage?

Tags: python

I had this all decoded and encoded. But I need to decode it using the encode I already have. I have to use the codeMessage list for this. I need to use a for loop and take each number from the list, decode it, and add it to a string. All using ASCII.

I've tried taking the "for m in message:" and changed ord() to chr() but it didn't work.

This is the working code I have:

```
def main():
    message = "We’re all fighting battles no one knows about."

    codeMessage = []

    message1 = [87, 101, 39, 114, 101, 32, 97, 108, 108, 32, 102, 105, 103, 104, 116, 105, 110, 103, 32, 98, 97, 116, 116, 108, 101, 115, 32, 110, 111, 32, 111, 110, 101, 32, 107, 110, 111, 119, 115, 32, 97, 98, 111, 117, 116, 46,]

    for m in message:
        codeMessage.append(ord(m))

    for c in codeMessage:
        print(c),

    print("This is what the numbers say translated back to english from ASCII:")
    print(chr(87) + chr(101) + chr(39) + chr(114) + chr(101) + chr(32) + chr(97) + chr(108) + chr(108) + chr(32) + chr(102) + chr(105) + chr(103) + chr(104) + chr(116) + chr(105) + chr(110) + chr(103) + chr(32) + chr(98) + chr(97) + chr(116) + chr(116) + chr(108) + chr(101) + chr(115) + chr(32) + chr(110) + chr(111) + chr(32) + chr(111) + chr(110) + chr(101) + chr(32) + chr(107) + chr(110) + chr(111) + chr(119) + chr(115) + chr(32) + chr(97) + chr(98) + chr(111) + chr(117) + chr(116) + chr(46))
```

I got the expected output but it was not the right way I was supposed to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I implemented. It is printing correct results on my IDE. Hope it helps your learning experience:

```
message = "We’re all fighting battles no one knows about."
codeMessage = []
message1 = [87, 101, 39, 114, 101, 32, 97, 108, 108, 32, 102, 105, 103, 104, 116, 105, 110, 103, 32, 98, 97, 116, 116, 108, 101, 115, 32, 110, 111, 32, 111, 110, 101, 32, 107, 110, 111, 119, 115, 32, 97, 98, 111, 117, 116, 46,]
for m in message:
    codeMessage.append(ord(m))

result = ""
for m in codeMessage:
    result = result + chr(m)

print(result)
```